# Android lazy load reload list images

Tags: android, listview, lazy-loading

I am trying to use listview in android.And i need get listItem images from server. I searched and found some codes. It works but when i scroll my listItem images are reloading.

Hereby my code

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View vi = convertView;


    if (vi == null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.movierow, parent, false);
    TextView txtMovieName = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.movieName);
    TextView textYear = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txtMovieYear);

    Movie   movie = data.get(position);

    String  strUrl=String.format( "http://yatanadam.com/FilmLines/admin/FilmImages/%d.png",movie.id);
    final ImageView img=(ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.imgMovieRow);

    img.setTag(position);

    new DownloadImageTask(img,position)
       .execute(strUrl);

    textYear.setText(movie.year);

    txtMovieName.setText(movie.name);

    return vi;
}

public class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
ImageView bmImageVw;
int imgVwId;


public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage,int id) {
    this.bmImageVw = bmImage;
    this.imgVwId=id;
}


protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
    String urldisplay = urls[0];
    Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
    try {
        InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
        mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error","ERRORdoInBackground");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return mIcon11;
}

protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {

    if (this.imgVwId==this.bmImageVw.getTag()){

        bmImageVw.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

[image: IMGSCROLLED]

[image: IMGFIRST]

Is there anyone can help me? I am on it over 4 hours.
Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use any of these libraries which helps to cache the loaded images.

- [Android-Universal-Image-Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)
- [Android volley](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/)

Sample app for android universal image loader has implemented loading images in listview. You can use it.

Answer (score 0):

1) Override the next method on your adapter:

```
@Override
public boolean hasStableIds(){ return true; }
```

2) Add a cache method to avoid download the image for the second time.
You can find more information about cache images on http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html

Hope this help